# How to connect to a wireless network programmatically?

Tags: java, networking

I have a java application and two different wireless network connections (wifi) on my desktop.
This is a desktop application, not android.

One method of this applicaiton works well with `wifi1`, second method works well with `wifi2`.

So far in order to use different methods I have to  change wifi settings on my desktop manually.

Is there any way I could change wifi connection setting from the application programmatically ?

Comment: You don't connect to networks. You connect to hosts, via networks. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java is a High-Level, Platform-Independent programming language.  Network settings, and how you control them will depend on your Operating System, and to my knowledge there is no simple way to expose this in Java.

'
Luckily, some platform-dependent code mixed with Java can help you achieve the result you're after.

1. **The Java**

   See the [Runtime.exec()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) method, which allows you access to the Windows Command Line or the Mac/Linux Terminal.
2. **The Windows (Adjust for other OS'es)**

   Now that we have access to the Command Line, we have to run the proper, platform-specific command.  See [this tutorial](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToConnectToAWirelessWIFINetworkFromTheCommandLineInWindows7.aspx) for Windows.

*Note that it is not a good idea to modify a user's network settings (or anything else external to your application) without their consent.*